# VSCode snippet that filters for URLs and emails

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

The following snippet creates a hyperlink by combining the selected text in a TeX file with (what is hopefully a URL in) the clipboard,

```
{
  "key": "cmd+l",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && resourceExtname == .tex",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "\\href{${CLIPBOARD:url}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the inserted clipboard content selected when executing the snippet? Moreover, is there a way to check whether the clipboard is a valid web or email address and only then insert it?

**Update**

Here's a non-working attempt at using a regex to only paste the clipboard content, when it's a url.

```
{
  "key": "cmd+l",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && resourceExtname == .tex",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "\\href{${1:${CLIPBOARD/(\\^\\(\\(https\\?\\)://\\)\\?\\(\\[w\\|W\\]\\{3\\}\\.\\)\\+\\[a-zA-Z0-9-\\.\\]\\{3,\\}\\.\\[a-zA-Z\\]\\{2,\\}\\(\\.\\[a-zA-Z\\]\\{2,\\}\\)\\?\\$)/$1/}}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this to work for your url validation regex?  I tried to play with the escapes and gave up.  It would be very useful if you could post your working url-version snippet.

Comment: No, I tried two url regexs that I found on stackoverflow but I couldn't get it to work ( yet). The email definitely works though so it should just be a problem of correctly escaping the url regex.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the url regex you included in your `Update`.  I have the escapes working.

Comment: Nice! Your answer has been very helpful! Wish I could get upvote it again. One small improvement would be to automatically prepend `mailto:` in front of the email address so that PDF readers recognize it as an email address and automatically open it in a mail client on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"snippet": "\\href{${1:${CLIPBOARD}}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0`

will print and select the `CLIPBOARD` content when you trigger the snippet.  You will lose the `url` hint though, I don't think there is a way to save that.

Your second question: "is there a way to check whether the clipboard is a valid web or email address and only then insert it?"

I believe so:

`${1:${CLIPBOARD/(..your regex test for email validity here..)/$1/}}`

**EDIT** (to check for valid **emails**) - tested:

`"snippet": "\\href{${1:${CLIPBOARD/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,})?(.*)/$1/i}}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0"`

I got the email regex from [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

This seems to work.  The key is that with snippet transforms if you don't match, in this case the CLIPBOARD variable content, the unmatched content will pass through and be printed.  In other words, if you don't capture it, it will pass through so the only way to prevent a bad email or url from passing through and being printed is to capture both a good email/url **and** the bad version and only print the good capture group.

So this is the basic form: `(regex email check here)?(.*)`

So group1 has the valid email, if any, and group2 has the ClipBoard content if it is not a valid email.  And only group1 is printed.  Neat.  Seems to work.

---

**EDIT 2** (to check for valid **urls**) - pseudocode:

`"snippet": "\\href{${1:${CLIPBOARD/(...url regex checker here...)?(.*)/$1/}}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0"`

so I  just added `?(.*)` to the end of an url regex check.

---

**EDIT 2.5**
Here is an **url** checker based on the one used in your Update snippet:

`"snippet": "\\href{${1:${CLIPBOARD/^((https?:\\/\\/)?([w]{3}\\.)+[a-z0-9-]{3,}\\.[a-z]{2,}(\\.[a-z]{2,})?)?(.*)$/$1${5:+bad url}/i}}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0"`

Note: regex's to validate urls are extremely tricky - if not impossible - I used the one from the question and make no warranties about its completeness.  At least you can see how to `escape` the regex.

---

**EDIT 3** **email/url** (if there is some text you want when a bad email/url is in the variable, in this case, $CLIPBOARD, but could be any variable):

Add this **conditional** `$1${2:+bad email}` to the replacement part of the snippet transform, so for the **email** version:

`"snippet": "\\href{${1:${CLIPBOARD/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,})?(.*)/$1${2:+bad email}/i}}}{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}$0"  // email validater`

whatever text you want in the `bad email` place.  Note, that checks if there is non-null content in group 2, if so, print "bad email".  Your regex may be using a different group to capture "bad emails/urls" - use that group in the conditional `${2:+bad email}`.

Comment: Nice! That works. The hint isn't that important. Not pasting in the clipboard unless it's actually a url or email is more important but I'm guessing that's not possible?

Comment: See the edits above, I think you should be able to put in a regex for valid emails - easy to find on the web - be sure to capture that entire regex in a group - surround it all with the `()` so it is group 1 - and then use that group as the replacement text `$1`.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. Didn't know VSCode provided that functionality. Can't get it work though. Neither escaped nor unescaped. Could you take a look at the update in my question to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As you say, really neat solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is there some text you want added where the url would normally go when the url is bad?  That might be fairly easy to add.

Comment: Probably best to just insert `url` if the clipboard is bad.